# How do I deploy custom Image Processing algorithms in an android app?

Tags: android, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I am building an app which will have a reverse image search feature for buildings, or landmarks. Simply speaking, Landmark Recognition for app. Now, I know about the Landmark Recognition API of ML Kit for Firebase thing but what if I want to deploy my own algorithm ?

My idea:
In app - Faster-RCNN for Feature Detection, Auto-Encoders for Image Denoising.
In server - Use Annoy Index for image search and retrieval.

Is this feasible ? What do you think ? Can I deploy my own Neural Networks in an android app using Tensorflow Lite or something ?

Is there any different approach you want to suggest ?

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy any `Tensorflow`, `Keras` and `pytorch` model on android devices using Tensorflow-lite. If you want to deploy your model for real time image/video processing then you should to go with [Mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe). Mediapipe is google framework build on the top of tensorflow-lite. Mediapipe performance is fast as compare to normal tflite deployment because it uses [Input/Output SSBO](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu_advanced#inputoutput_buffers), It is cross platforms as well.

Comment: Nice, did not know about MediaPipe.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is clearly to use TensorFlow Lite.

Before you deploy it to your Android Device, you can test it locally in Python, using an interpreter on the spot(in your case the real interpreter is your Android Device, but for testing purposes, you can also run your code in Python).

Comment: I read TensorFlow Lite docs and saw that there are pre-trained models for object detection and segmentation. I actually have a normal code ready with the CNNs and working. Can I deploy my self written codes on TensorFlow Lite ? Or are you suggesting me to replace my segmentation and detection models with TensorFlow Lite's pre-trained models ?

Comment: You can train your own models on top of pretrained models. But if you are satisfied with the pretrained model, you can go ahead and place it in your app.

Comment: Depending on what you exactly intend to do. As Shubham Panchal mentioned, you may try using the pertained model. However, if the pretrained model does not have the classes that you are interested in, it will be useful to start from a pretrained model and by means of transfer learning train on your custom dataset.